# android-sqlite - isOpen returns nullpointerexception in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my database class:

```
public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
Context context;

public OpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    ........
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public DatabaseHandler open() {
        helper = new OpenHelper(context);
        myDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        myDB.close();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        if(myDB.isOpen()) return true ; else return false; 
    }
```

}

Every function I have works fine like insert and update, but when I want to check if the database is open or not, it crashes. I call it in activity like this:

```
DatabaseHandler mydb=new DatabaseHandler(context);
            if(!mydb.isOpen())
                mydb.open();
```

It keeps erroring on this line:

```
if(!mydb.isOpen())
```

It returns a `nullpointerexception` and I don't know why.

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: are you assigning anything to context after its declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `isOpen()` before `open()` and the `mydb` you use in `isOpen()` is only initialized in `open()`.

As a quick fix, change

```
if(myDB.isOpen())
```

to something like

```
if(myDb != null && myDB.isOpen())
```